# Moving or copying files from one directory to multiple directories

Tags: shell

I have a directory `/input/source` that contains files like:

```
$ ls -1 /input/source
FileName_1.txt
FileName_2.txt
FileName_3.txt
FileName_4.txt
```

I also have a file named `/tmp/temp_path.txt` that contains the following paths (or directories) information like:

```
$ cat /tmp/temp_path.txt
/output/dest/temp_1
/output/dest/temp_2
/output/dest/temp_3
/output/dest/temp_4
```

I am trying to build a shell script which will read the path info from `/tmp/temp_path.txt` and then **move** the files from the `source` folder to the respective directories as follows

```
/output/dest/temp_1/FileName_1.txt
/output/dest/temp_2/FileName_2.txt
/output/dest/temp_3/FileName_3.txt
/output/dest/temp_4/FileName_4.txt
```

Also, wanted to do some checks and balances before moving the files to destination path like:

```
if count of dest path from file(/tmp/temp_path.txt) != count of input files from source folder
    then move randomly
else
    move sequentially
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Minor nit (which needs to be brought up now and again).  Directories do not contain files.  Directories contain names.  If the directory `/input/source` contains the name `FileName_1.txt` and you create the name `FileName_1.txt` in the directory `/output/dest/temp_1` which references (is a link to) the same file, you haven't moved the file at all.  You've just created a new name.  Of course, if the destination directory is on a different filesystem, a full copy of all the data may be necessary, and the new name may link to a different file.  Sometimes these distinctions really matter.

Comment: Hi William, it’s about movement of files from a single source directory to multiple destination directories and the path of the destination directories are read from a file. It’s NOT about creating files manually and linking between them across single vs multiple destinations.

Comment: @SG2022, have you tried to do it with the help of e.g. bash? If yes, can you please also add it to the question?

Comment: @SG2022 No, it's not about "movement of files" at all.  That's that point of my comment.  The files do not reside in the directory, and the files are not moved.  Because directories do not contain files.  They just contain names.  But (and this is why I call it a "minor nit") this is probably an esoteric point that most people don't think about.  But occasionally, it becomes extremely important.